# migrating email public folders from cyrus imap to exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, migration, imap

I'm trying to find out the best way of migrating a public folder structure from cyrus imap to exchange 2010.

We have about 300Gb of emails in a public folder structure on a cyrus-imap server, that we want to migrate to exchange 2010.

Initially I was thinking of using outlook to login to the imap server and do a drag & drop to move the folders and emails.  The problem with that is that outlook caches everything to local disk of the client first before pushing it to exchange.  Also it is terribly slow.

Is there a tool or script that will enable me to migrate the public folder structure to the public folder database in exchange.  Or is there another way of doing this that is relatively quick and simple to do.

To make it easier I am not concerned at the ACLs being migrated over as I am planning on using this opportunity to tidy the folders up a bit.  However the first problem is getting them on to Exchange 2010 in the first place.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

imapsync is very good at migrating mailboxes over imap.  I've done it many times from cyrus to cyrus, and I've read reports of users using it with exchange.

If you have authentication capabilities, this may work for you:

http://freshmeat.net/projects/imapsync/

Answer (score 0):

Outlook with drag'n'drop is the only solution I've ever found to this scenario, and I've dug around quite a bit. Sorry for not having any other magical answer :)